# Why is TextDecorationCollection always empty in WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, underline

I've seen some questions address this problem domain and the unnecessary complexity of handling underlines (mainly applying them, but I want to detect them), but none that I can recall suggesting as I am here that the default strategies for accomplishing this create illogical false negatives. Furthermore, most of the previous questions I've referred to have used a different control (e.g. TextBlock) and/or have obselete syntax.

### The problem

(.NET Core 3.1) I would simply like to programatically detect if a WPF RichTextBox selection contains any TextDecorations, but debugging shows that the TextDecorationCollection is always empty, even when the selection is all underlined.

[image: debugging screenshot showing that TextDecorationCollection returns empty even when examining a fully underlined Inline (Run)]
As you can see, TextDecorationCollection returns empty even when examining a fully underlined Inline (Run)

[image: FlowDocument format for the document in question]
For context, this screenshot just shows the plain text representation of the FlowDocument

### What I've tried

1

```
TextRange myrange = new TextRange(MainRtb.Selection.Start, MainRtb.Selection.End);
if (myrange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty).Equals(TextDecorations.Underline)) { }
```

2

```
TextRange myrange = new TextRange(MainRtb.Selection.Start, MainRtb.Selection.End);
var obj = myrange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);

if (obj == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) {
    log.addLog("mix format");
}
if (obj is TextDecorationCollection) {
    var objProper = obj as TextDecorationCollection;

    if (objProper.Count > 0) {
        log.addLog("all underlined");
    } else {
        log.addLog("none underlined");
    }
}
```

3

```
foreach (Block block in MainRtb.Document.Blocks) {
    Paragraph p = block as Paragraph;
    if (p != null) {
        foreach (Inline inline in p.Inlines) {
            InlineUIContainer iuic = inline as InlineUIContainer;
            if (iuic != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("found underline");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Theory

This post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3ac626cf-60aa-427f-80e9-794f3775a70e/how-to-tell-if-richtextbox-selection-is-underlined?forum=wpf suggests that

```
myrange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty)
```

doesn't work properly due to an issue inside the "GetPropertyValue()" method, but it's a very old post. I couldn't run Jim's solution exactly because he initialises an "IEnumerable" which now needs to be declared with a type of some kind - at least that's what VS2019 said.

Test Rtf File:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YQmGsPcH4hX2XsP7KBdFqTFg4XjrSv8I/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111968029811979231347&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Try to call in one line: `var decors = MainRtb.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);` Did you receive `decors.Count` equal `0`? **1)** What is your environment: Framework or .Core, Visual Studio version? Because of this code is working for me. **2)** Can you load your rtf document in the text format to be able check this in my test application?

Comment: Hey Victor! This project is on .Core 3.1

Comment: Also I can't run your suggestion because I can't do .Count on a var

Comment: Put breakpoint and point to the `decors` in the debugger. What version of the Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\qc\b\f0\fs22\lang9 By default, the \fs32 caret \b0 is at the \i\fs22 first insertion position \i0\fs52 at the beginning \fs22 of the content hosted by the RichTex\ul tBox. See TextPointer for more information on text position terminology like "insertion position"\par
\par

\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\qr ghfd\par
\par

\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1 gfdgfdgfdgdf gfdrju9h0gfdjnk grdf87356478y90345678y03645ionjh\ulnone\par
}

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I've tried your line with a breakpoint and it's still Count 0 for me.

Comment: This works for me in VS 2019 + WPF App .Core 3.1 . It's seems like something special in you RTF document. Try to test with empty `RichTextBox`, but type some text and use `Ctrl+B` or `Ctrl+U` to format this text and, for example, select only one letter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245898/discussion-between-micsupreeme-and-victor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following method:

```cs
public static void GetDecorations(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextDecorationCollection decors = rtb.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection;
    if (decors == null || decors.Count == 0)
    {
        if (rtb.Selection.Start.Parent is Run run) 
        {
            if (run.Parent is Span span)
            {
                decors = span.TextDecorations;
            }
            else if (run.Parent is Paragraph para)
            {
                decors = para.TextDecorations;
            }
        }
    }

    if (decors is TextDecorationCollection tdc)
    {
        // TODO: Processing decorations...  
    }
}
```

I suppose the problem you are discovered is related to the particular structure of the `FlowDocument` after loading your RTF document and it might be described as follow.

When the RTF document is loaded for the underlined text [`tBox. See TextPointer for more information on text position terminology like "insertion position"`](https://stackoverflow.com/) a `Run` inline is created for this text, but the `Run.TextDecorations` property doesn't contain the actual decorations for this text. Instead of that the decorations settings are stored in the parent `Span` object that contains this `Run`. In another words, these decorations property is inherited from parent to child.

Therefore, if no decorations property is set on the current `Run` object, then you should to check the `TextDecorations` property in the parent object.